# Colocar valores de um memo dentro de um array

Tags: delphi

Tenho o seguinte componente `Memo` com os textos:

```
200:80
177:3306
```

Preciso colocar esse texto dentro de um *array*, por exemplo, se baseando na primeira linha, o texto *200* (seria `array[1]`) e o campo *80* (seria `array[2]`). Lembrando que preciso usar como delimitador o `:` (dois pontos), e na sequência percorrer esse mesmo e mostrar em um `ShowMessage`.

Não consigo fazer isso de forma nenhuma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a [função **`ExtractStrings`**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Classes.ExtractStrings)

```
Var
 Numeros: TStringList;
 Numero: string;
begin
 Numeros := TStringList.Create;

 Memo1.Clear;
 Memo1.Lines.Add('200:80');
 Memo1.Lines.Add('177:3306');

 try
   ExtractStrings([':'], [], pchar(Memo1.Text), Numeros);

   for Numero in Numeros do begin
     Showmessage(Numero);
   end;

 finally
   Numeros.Free;
 end;
```

Comment: @user7605 `ShowMessage(Numeros.Text);`?

Comment: desculpe, falei errado. O Memo tem várias linhas, ele está mostrando somente a primeira no showmessage, entende ?

Comment: @user7605 `ShowMessage(Numeros[0]);` mostrará o primeiro item do *array*, `ShowMessage(Numeros.Text);` mostrará todos os itens contidos neste *array*. Os `Memo1.Lines.Add(...)` é apenas um exemplo.

Comment: @user7605 No exemplo acima, para mostrar o valor *80*, você faz: `ShowMessage(Numeros[1]);` e assim por diante...

Comment: obrigado pela paciência. Existe uma forma se eu colocar assim: ShowMessage(Numeros[0]);  ele mostrar todos desse array de uma vez ? Tipo, mostra um, eu dou OK, na sequencia mostra outro e assim por diante ?

Comment: @user7605 Atualizei a resposta, veja se é isto.

Comment: Perfeito amigo, obrigado!